# Simple way to read Json file on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-json

I have a JSON file containing a list of countries and I want to integrate it into my android studio java project then read the content via code, where to put the file in the project and what's the easiest way to read the file in my Java classes?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: not really, the guy already read the file content and is looking on how to prase it

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you have to read the file and assign the content to some string variable

   ```
        val file = File(context?.filesDir, FILE_NAME)
    val fileReader = FileReader(File(context?.filesDir, FILE_NAME))
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(fileReader)
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        stringBuilder.append("${line}\n")
        line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    }
    bufferedReader.close()
    val jsonFileAsString = stringBuilder.toString()
   ```

2.Secondly, you have to create a JSONOBJECT from the previous result (*the **jsonFileAsString** variable*)

```
 val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonFileAsString)
```

3. Finally, to read a specific property you can use

   `jsonObject.get("name").toString()`

But to make things clear you should consider making a **data class** to match specific JSON file and parse it that way. To do this you can use GSON library (I dunno if standard Android packages have this functionality) and you should get something like this:

the data class

```
data class Transport(
    val TransportIdentifier: String?,
    val TransportType: String?,
)
```

and to parse it you simply use

```
val transport = Gson().fromJson<Transport>(stringVariable, Transport::class.java)
```

and can use it like

```
transport.TransportType
```

To make things even more simplier, you can generate a data class from the JSON output using for example [online-parser](https://www.json2kotlin.com/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, my file is actually a .json not .txt, does it make any difference? and also where should I put it on my project?

Comment: it doesn't make any difference. Where you should put it depends on if you are getting the file via some WebApi or is it a static file that you are using throughout the whole app